# Determining Graph Automorphisms by Determining Ways of Permuting Edges

Tags: graph-theory, symmetry

Here is an example from the book Groups, Graphs, and Trees (Ignore example 1.15; I accidently included it in my snippet of the pdf):

[image]

From my understanding, the symmetry group of a graph $\Gamma$ consists of all bijections $f : V(\Gamma) \to V(\Gamma)$ such that $v,w$ are adjacent vertices if and only if $f(v),f(w)$ are adjacent vertices. So, to construct the symmetry group $Sym(\Gamma)$, we just need to look at the ways which we can map vertices to vertices in such a way that adjacency is preserved.

However, in this example, the author is merely looking at the ways to permute the edges. Strictly speaking, elements in $Sym(\Gamma)$ don't act on edges. Is there another notion of symmetry ("edge" symmetry) which corresponds to the usual symmetry ("vertex" symmetry)? Correspond to in the sense that the "edge" symmetry group is isomorphic to the "vertex" symmetry group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like authors call graph what is usually called multigraph with non-labeled edges - they allow existence of multiple edges connecting the same pair of vertices. For such graphs automorphishm is a function acting on both vertices and edges that preserves incidence.

Comment: In the field of geometric group theory, one typically refers to any one-dimensional CW complex as just a *graph,* and refers to graphs where every edge corresponds uniquely to a pair of distinct vertices as a *simple* or *simplicial graph.*

Comment: So, as a function what is the domain/codomain of a graph automorphism $f$? It can't just be $V(\Gamma)$. Is it $V(\Gamma) \cup E(\Gamma)$, with the stipulation that $f(V(\Gamma)) \subseteq V(\Gamma)$ and $f(E(\Gamma)) \subseteq E(\Gamma)$?

Comment: Yes, it is defined on $V \cup E$, such that $F(V) = V$, $F(E) = E$ and if $\langle x, y\rangle \in E$ then $f(\langle x, y\rangle) = \langle f(x), f(y)\rangle$.

Comment: @mihaild I'm still a little confused. Why does it suffice to keep the vertices fixed and just look at the ways of rearranging the edges in order to determine $Sym(\Gamma)$?

Comment: It's not. But in this case group of automorphisms is direct product of it's two subgroups, one of which keeps vertices fixed (and the other keeps most edges fixed).

Comment: @mihaild If we are a dealing with a graph with multiple graphs, such as the one given above, isn't $\langle x,y \rangle \in E$ ambiguous? How does one deal with this ambiguity? It doesn't appear that the definition of symmetry given in my book can handle this.

Comment: Yes, my comment probably was more confusing then it should be, sorry. In case of multigraph we can think of edges as pair of set of edges $E$ and function $x\colon E \to V \times V$ that gives endpoints of edge. Then $f$ is automorphism of $\Gamma$ if $f\colon V \cup E \to V \cup E$ such that $f(V) = V$, $f(E) = E$ and $x(f(e)) = f(x(e))$ (the right hand is element-wise application) for any $e \in E$ .

Comment: @mihaild Ah, interesting. My book actually describes a function called Ends, defined to be a function such that "each edge [is] associated to an unordered pair of vertices...$Ends(e) = \{v,w\}$, where $v,w \in V$. Then in the definition of a symmetry $f$, there is the requirement (among others) that if $Ends(e) = \{v,w\}$, then $Ends(f(e)) = \{f(v),f(w)\}$. This is basically the function $x$ you describe, right? So, $f$ doesn't induce a function on the edges; it's already a function on the edges.

Comment: You are right. And we can't define $f$ on vertices and then deduce $f$ on edges, as there can be symmetries that are id on vertices but non-id on edges.